# Trying to make a carousel slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im trying to make a simple carousel slider with 3 slides with some content inside, now the problem is that i cant make to go to the first slide when im on the last one, so i would be thankful if anyone can give few pointers where im wrong.

Take a look:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNpYLB`enter code here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `slide` class to each slide. Optionally, declare `slider-content[x]` as an `id` (don't forget to modify the CSS accordingly):

```
<div class="slide" id="slider-content3">
```

Conduct analogical operation on the dots list:

```html
<ul class="slider-dots">
  <li class="dot active-dot">&bull;</li>
  <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
  <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
</ul>
```

And change your javascript to:

```js
 if(nextSlide.length === 0) {
        nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
 nextDot = $('.dot').first();
}
```

Check on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPNOwR) if it's the desired behaviour.

Comment: Noo you made it work!!! Just kidding :D thank you sir, i wanted to try myself with few tips but this is more than i asked for. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Oh, sorry for spoiling the fun ;)